# How can I arrange Dart classes within a file in alphabetical order in VS Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have created a file as follows:

```dart
class SampleConst {
  static const box = 'box';
}

class CommonConst {
  static const common = 'common';
}
```

In cases like this, the classes are not sorted in alphabetical order by name. So, I searched for the feature to arrange class names in alphabetical order using vscode's standard functionality or extensions, but I couldn't find it. How can this be achieved?

Comment: write a script (Python, JavaScript,...) that parses the file, stores the file in a list with key the class name, sort by classname, write the blocks back. This is a language dependent feature (parsing) and I have never come across this so no language server will have implemented it